# What is the best way to call a asynchronous Function in Javascript(Angular) with some delay/sleep. Setimeout doesn't allow to do the same

Tags: javascript, angular, timer, async-await, polling

I'm working on creating API polling on some async function which is called from another async function. Something like below code:

```
public generatePreview() {
this.apiService.firstAPI().subscribe(async headers => {
  // Do some processing over here
  await this.getRows();
});
}


  public async getRows() {
    this.apiService.secondAPI().subscribe(async rows => {
      if (rows.status === 'INGESTION_IN_PROGRESS') {
        console.log('inside');
        setTimeout(()=>{return await this.getRows()}, 5000);
      } else if (rows.status === 'COMPLETED') {
          // Stopping Logic
      }
    });
  }
```

Explanation : **generatePreview** function calls a firstAPi function, calls out **getRows** function which has the polling logic . If async call response has status 'INGESTION_IN_PROGRESS', It should call **getRows** again(with some delay). When I put it inside **setTimeout**, I get the following error *''await' expression is only allowed within an async function.'*.

I am looking for best options to achieve the polling with some timer.

Comment: maybe use Promise constructor to construct a new promise which waits and resolves after delay has passed. Else you may try to async/await in setTimeout but instead of returning value simply set a global var with the result and check if it is set later on, but 1st option is better